# Azure IoT Hub - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub

This morning I tried to go through Microsoft's 
[tutorial for connecting to an Azure IoT Hub with .NET.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted)

The only differences being the name of my hub, and that I chose the standard S1 pricing tier as I am planning to 'grow' my prototype using this tutorial as a start point.

However when I try to run the console apps, the Receive client throws an error at the following:

```
var d2cPartitions = eventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformation().PartitionIds;
```

The full error message is as follows:

```
  Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingCommunicationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  IsTransient=true
  Message=An error occurred during communication with 'DeviceGateway_{auto generated alphanumeric string here}:iothub-ns-{auto generated connection details here}.servicebus.windows.net:5671'. Check the connection information, then retry.
  Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionExtensions.ThrowException(Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionExtensions.Rethrow(Exception exception)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.RunSynchronously()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpEventHubClient.GetRuntimeInformation()
       at ReadDeviceToCloudMessages.Program.Main(String[] args) in R:\SRE_Prototypes\IoTHubGetStarted\ReadDeviceToCloudMessages\Program.cs:line 22
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       ErrorCode=10061
       HResult=-2147467259
       Message=No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
       NativeErrorCode=10061
       Source=mscorlib
       StackTrace:
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionExtensions.Rethrow(Exception exception)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.Transport.AmqpTransportInitiator.ConnectAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.Transport.AmqpTransportInitiator.EndConnect(IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.ConnectAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__13_3(ConnectAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionExtensions.Rethrow(Exception exception)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.ConnectAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result, ConnectInfo& info)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.RedirectConnectionManager.OnEndCreateInstance(IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonDictionaryManager`2.LoadInstanceAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__13_3(LoadInstanceAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
         --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.ExceptionExtensions.Rethrow(Exception exception)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonDictionaryManager`2.LoadInstanceAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonDictionaryManager`2.EndLoadInstance(IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.RedirectConnectionManager.EndGetConnection(IAsyncResult result)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessagingFactory.OpenLinkAsyncResult.<>c.<GetAsyncSteps>b__35_11(OpenLinkAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
            at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)
       InnerException:
```

My research so far suggests this is some sort of server setup problem, and usually caused by either needing to open ports, change firewall settings, however
A) I cant find anywhere in the Azure dashboard to do this
B) I would have thought it will be configured correctly for this by default

Is there something obvious that i'm missing, or do I need to go and start chasing my IT department to see if they are blocking it?

Comment: You can use this Powershell command to test the Service Bus connection for AMQP and show the result. `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName watchdog.servicebus.windows.net -Port 5671`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no configuration required in the Azure portal to open any ports. However, the Receive Client application in the tutorial needs to have port 5671 open (it communicates with IoT Hub using the AMQP protocol) - it maybe that the firewall configuration on your computer, or your corporate firewall blocks this port.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response.  That's more or less what I thought, so I'll fire a message off to IT and see what they have to say.

Comment: Apologies to all for the late update, but I've only just got back to this project.  It was indeed a firewall issue.  Port 5671 was needed for the receive application, and port 8883 is required for MQTT in the send application